# Image as checkbox in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4, pyqt5

Is it possible with Python to use image as a checkbox (in a GUI app made with PyQT)? For example, there is a image of a blue circle, and when you click on it, it becomes red.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Perhaps you should try writing a small example (hint: use a `QLabel` for the image/button), and then come back if/when you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for this challenge:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *


def chk():
    global button, checked

    checked = not checked
    ic = icon1 if checked else icon2
    button.setIcon(ic)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = QWidget()
layout = QHBoxLayout()
widget.setLayout(layout)

checked = True
button = QPushButton()
button.setFlat(True)
button.clicked.connect(chk)
button.setStyleSheet('border:none')
layout.addWidget(button)

icon1 = QIcon("off.png")
icon2 = QIcon("on.png")
button.setIcon(icon1)
button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))

widget.show()
app.exec_()
```